# Why can't I check to see if my array of arrays contains a specific array?

Tags: arrays, swift, contains

I'm trying to check to see if an array of arrays contains an array of Strings. My error message says:

"Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument list of type '([([(String)])]), [(String)])'"

```
var allCards = [[String]]()
var exp1 = [String]()

if !contains(allcards, exp1) {
    allCards.append(exp1)
}
```

What's going on!?

Comment: The class used in contains method should implement Equatable protocol. As it is required to check whether two elements are equal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array` does not conform to the `Equatable` protocol, therefore

```
/// Return `true` iff `x` is in `seq`.
func contains<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element : Equatable>(seq: S, x: S.Generator.Element) -> Bool
```

cannot be used here. You can use the predicate-based variant

```
/// Return `true` iff an element in `seq` satisfies `predicate`.
func contains<S : SequenceType, L : BooleanType>(seq: S, predicate: @noescape (S.Generator.Element) -> L) -> Bool
```

instead:

```
var allCards = [[String]]()
var exp1 = [String]()

if !contains(allCards, { $0 == exp1 } ) {
    allCards.append(exp1)
}
```

because `==` is defined for arrays of `Equatable` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Update for **`Swift2`**:

`contains()` is now a function defined in a protocol extension of `Sequence` therefore:

```
var allCards = [[String]]()
var exp1 = [String]()

if !allCards.contains( { $0 == exp1 } ) {
    allCards.append(exp1)
}
```